# how to create binary index with ruby on rails active record?

Tags: ruby-on-rails, sql-server, postgresql, activerecord, oracle11g

My 'Actions' table contains some discrete values fields : Status, Priority, Mode. (I work with Postgres, Oracle, MSSQL databases).

I'd like to be able to sort out Actions based on theses fields, so I think of using a bitmap index.
I can't find the syntax for this type of indexes in Rails guides.

Can someone give me a hint?

Thanks!

Answer (score 1):

You should  refer on  `add_index` api and use `using` parameter.
 http://apidock.com/rails/ActiveRecord/ConnectionAdapters/SchemaStatements/add_index

something like

```
add_index(:users, :name, using: 'gist')
```

For more, refer source code

https://github.com/rails/rails/blob/d09a9bc07ddaf3c570aced434ab64cf06860678c/activerecord/lib/active_record/connection_adapters/abstract/schema_statements.rb#L555

Comment: Sorry, my question was not specific enough. I know the API, but I am searching for something like using: 'bitmap'. Would gist fulfill this requirement?